# Eclipse Shortcut to print all method parameters of java

Tags: java, eclipse

For logging in the remote server I constantly need to print the parameters of a method to see if this method getting correct parameter.

Is there a way to print all method parameter (if they are object then with `toString`) in one shot. For example:

```
 void doSomething(String anyString, Object anyObject)
{
    System.out.println("anyString : "+anyString+" anyObject: "+anyObject.toString());
 // I want to generate above line in one shot.
}
```

Option 1: 
Source Generator :
We use source generator to generate `toString` `equals()` `hashCode()` using class variable. SO, is there any way to add another option in source generator to support this.?

Option 2: Using Template  :
we write some code block using suggested snippet. like `foreach`, `while` , `try-catch`.

Note: I tried adding a custom template for this purpose, but i was just able to print the parameters name using `${enclosing_method_arguments}`. Is there any way to use this?

Option 3: Our Suggestion .

Comment: "(if they are object then with toString)" String concatenation automatically calls `toString()` on an object if it's non-null, or inserts `null` if it is null. Do you want a NPE if the parameter is null?

Comment: well i guess then without calling `toString()` putting them as they are in String concate will be good idea. But Still don't know how to do that :(